# Is window.location() same as a GET request?

Tags: javascript, get, window.location

Are cookies preserved while doing `windows.location(url)`, if domain of url is the domain of the current page?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes**. It's the same thing and it will retain all cookies.

Answer (score 15):

To be *really* pedantic, changing `window.location` in Javascript will cause the browser to go to another site, *which includes making a GET request*. In other words, a GET request and Javascripts `window.location` are two completely different things; one is a type of HTTP request, the other a DOM attribute.

As pertains to the question though, they can be considered equivalent. Cookies are preserved.

`</pedantry>` :)

Comment: +1 for satisfying my semantics teacher back in philosophy 101.